# How to handle non-required parameters in Swagger to avoid missing positional argument error?

Tags: python-3.x, swagger, connexion

I have a Swagger file for my endpoints, one of my endpoints has several parameters. How do you handle non-required parameters? I'm having a challenge on how to handle it on my Python file if the non-required parameters have empty value.

Here is my Swagger definition:

```yaml
/surveyData:
    get:
      operationId: "surveyData.read_surveydata"
      summary: Gets the survey data for the client insights tracker.
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: startDate
          type: string
          required: true
          description: The start date of the survey data.
        - in: query
          name: endDate
          type: string
          required: true
          description: The end date of the survey data.
        - in: query
          name: country
          type: string
          description: The countries from which you would like to filter the survey data.
        - in: query
          name: market
          type: string
```

and here is my function which is written in Python (using Connexion):

```
def read_surveydata(startDate, endDate, country, market):
```

Comment: I believe not, this question is regarding the framework Connexion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the "Default" tag for example:

```
      parameters:
        - name: filtros
          in: "query"
          required: false
          description: Filter to query
          type: "string"
          default: "bndu"
```

Or add a default argument

```py
def read_surveydata(startDate, endDate, country, market='store'):
```

Comment: Hi @Kevin Martins, thank you! this give me some insights, but how's your approach in the query, by the way, do you use ORM or an SQL query?

Comment: Hi @PaulCaballero I am using the sqlalchemy ORM https://www.sqlalchemy.org/

Comment: Hi @Kevin Martins, yes, I'm using Stored Procedure though. Thank you!

Comment: @PaulCaballero Good ! If you need anything, just talk :)